# databinding of datatemplate wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a listbox in content panel which have a data template in which there is a text box whici is binded to a dependency property of underlying page. Textbox when tapped should update its text. Its working fine without data template but in data template text box is not updating.

Comment: Show your xaml and code so that we can better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figure it out. We cant access controls inside data template by there names.